# Is there a way to see our 'Flagger Rating?'

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, flags

With the [new flagging changes](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/01/improved-flagging/), our flags get weighted based on how (un)helpful the have been in the past.  Is there a way to see this value?  I'd be interested to know if my flags are effective or not.

If we had this info, we could adjust our flagging behavior if our flags are proving unhelpful or continue our good behavior if our flags have been helpful.

Since I am now casting more flags because of the [/review](https://stackoverflow.com/review/) page, this would be very helpful.

Comment: Grace Note said that "if you aren't receiving an email of complaint about 'turbulent' behavior, you're flagging right and should just proceed as you usually do." Since the discussion on that answer kind of went in a different direction, I'll ask here: __is this actually the paradigm that most mods follow in practice?__

Comment: @Popular Since even before this "rated flagging" system was implemented, I've witnessed many discussions about the subject of inappropriate flagging. One particularly egregious one with sticks to mind. Like with any other behavior that needs to be corrected, the best way to go about it has been to contact the user via email to suggest an amendment to the activity. So I'm inclined to believe that most moderators do indeed follow this kind of general essence of responding when users are being problematic via flags.

Comment: I've always wondered if every mod was thinking OMG this fat bastard keeps flagging posts!

Comment: Using your [flag count](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/79742/are-the-new-moderator-flag-limits-sufficiently-high/80117#80117), you can now roughly determine your flag weight.

Comment: You can see this on your profile now.

Comment: Moderators can also see the flag weight for some users (those who are above or below average).

Comment: @badp, I figured the Mods would be able to see this info too.  I wish I could see it as well.  I think it would be interesting to see.

Comment: @jjnguy You can see yours if it's special enough. :) On Gaming you need ~150 to be above average. On Meta, 190 is above average.

Comment: @badp, Oh I'm special!  I'd like to compare my special-ness with everyone else's.  `:)`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Deleted my old answer since, well, it got overridden, *and* invalidated by the flagger rating actually becoming useful to know (it gives you bonus mod flags, now!).

On your profile, beneath your gravatar and number of views, is your flagger rating. To understand the number, I'll quote [Marc Gravell from the implementation post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/79742/are-the-new-moderator-flag-limits-sufficiently-high/80117#80117)

> [...]what is flag weight?
>
> Simply: it is the way we order flagged posts. They still get looked at, but flags by known-good flaggers get seen first. We'll add this to your own profile shortly, but basically:
>
> - start at 100
> - +10 for a flagged post (+5 for a comment) that we did something about (or was basically valid)
> - -10 for a flagged post (-5 for a comment) that we suppressed as invalid
> - min 25, max 500
>
> If your flag weight is low you can quickly recover it simply by flagging sensibly. "I disagree with this" is a bad reason to flag, as is "plz answer post is urgent mail me".

*If you don't see a number there, then [you are at an average flagger rating](http://chat.meta.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/524908#524908)*. That is, you're hovering around the default 100 area.

Comment: I am not seeing this on my profile, has it gone out to the servers yet?

Comment: @Ian Oh, right. I'll note something that was tangentially pointed out. See the part at the bottom.

Comment: how match history is included in the rating, e.g. does it go back weeks, or just a day or two

Comment: @Ian I assume it goes for the full life of your account, up to when flagger rating was implemented (we didn't have valid/invalid prior to the system, so there's nothing to rate from then).

Comment: Apologies for waking a sleeping question but does this still apply? If so, where do we see the flag weight? I can't find it.