# How do users know if they're flagging properly?

Tags: support, flags

> **Possible Duplicate:**
> [Is there a way to see our 'Flagger Rating?'](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/74969/is-there-a-way-to-see-our-flagger-rating)

According to the [Improved Flagging blog post](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/01/improved-flagging/), Stack Exchange now tracks flag reliability:

> If a particular user keeps moderator flagging for reasons that we consider invalid, their flag weight decreases. And for those users who continually flag reliably, their flag weight increases.

Is there a way for users to see their own flag reliability scores? Or get any kind of feedback on their flag quality at all, short of revisiting each flagged item to see whether/what action was taken?

In the past, bookmarking flagged posts and comments locally and revisiting them later might have been sufficient, but not anymore. The new system's increased flag volume, in conjunction with the `/review` page, makes it easy for users to blow through all 10-30 of their daily flags in 15 minutes. (Yes, I know some users have >30 flags/day, but they're the exception, not the rule; even on SO, there are only ~350 of them.)

Feedback will let reliable flaggers know that they're doing the right thing, and reinforce their good behavior. At the same time, it will be a hint to unreliable flaggers that they should change their flagging practices and/or their mindset about what constitutes valid content on the site they're on.

So: is some kind of flag feedback available? If so, where? If not, it should be.

Comment: Related - most of your questions are already asked over at http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/74969/is-there-a-way-to-see-our-flagger-rating. I'm still of the opinion that it should be implicit that the flagging is proper until a moderator directly contacts you to tell you otherwise, and that those curious can always just ask directly. All the aggregate rating affects is the positioning - the more important data on why they get dismissed is only known by the moderators.

Comment: This would be useful; Newgrounds (which inspired this) publicly displays every user's whistle level on their profile. The exact score isn't displayed but the level is. [My main account is doing just fine for example.](http://n00b-l0s3r.newgrounds.com)

Comment: I have a feature request supporting this: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/74969/is-there-a-way-to-see-our-flagger-rating

Comment: D'oh! And I spent so much time composing this post....

Comment: Tisk tisk!  learn to search `:P`