# Are the new moderator flag limits sufficiently high?

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, flags

[Last month](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/01/improved-flagging/), the flag limits got an increase based on reputation points:

> In order to encourage more flagging, we have increased the number of general moderator flags available to 10 per day, plus one per every 1k of reputation, up to a maximum of 100. So if you have 15k reputation, you now have 25 moderator flags to use each day as you see fit. The existing spam and offensive flag allocation of 5 per day has not changed.

As an experiment, for the past few days I've been going to the [review page](https://stackoverflow.com/review) and browsing for a short while. I found that **I can invariably find more posts that need attention than I can flag**. Mostly these are non-answers found in the ["late answers" tab](https://stackoverflow.com/review/late-answers).

My guess is that any user can reach the flag limit in roughly `2 * n` minutes or (much) less, where n = number of flags available. I think this is unfortunate, given that our moderators seem to be doing a [great job](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/77777/why-no-fanfare-about-our-new-moderator-overlords) taking care of flags.

Note that I'm lacking some insight as to how important flags are to the moderation process. If there are any statistics on the volume of valid flags requiring moderator action vs. the volume of moderator actions without flags, it would help answer this question. I'm trying to get an idea of *how much* flags are helping, and potentially *how much more* they could be helping.

I like an [idea](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/8935/increase-the-number-of-daily-spam-flags-with-reputation/9021#9021) in another question which addressed flag limits. I understand that the newly-implemented flag limits are already merit-based. However, I ask:

1. How many users actually use all their flags?
2. Is reputation alone really a good metric by which flag limits should be set? (See item 1.)

My point with these questions is: Given that flags are useful to moderators, users with 10 flags per day who regularly flag 10 posts which legitimately require attention are helping the moderation process much more than users with 25 or even 50 flags who only flag every once in a while (however rare these users may, in reality, be-- I'm *not* trying to say that the additional flags go unused).

Furthermore, one moderator has [expressed in a comment](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/59386/total-number-of-moderator-flags-per-day/59389#59389) that:

> We'd rather have too many flags than not enough.

Especially considering that point, I think it would be a good idea to supplement the new flagging limits with a multiplier based on the "flagging reliability" metric (which was also mentioned in the announcement about the new limits). I understand that this is now already used in weighting flags in the moderator queue, but **would it be appropriate to apply flag reliability to the flagging limits as well?**

Answer (score 63, accepted):

Until a few days ago, the calculation was:

- default 10 per day
- one bonus flag per 1000 reputation
- maximum 100

But we have now tweaked this to consider previous flagging history: flags by people who flag well are OK

so:

- default 10 per day
- one bonus flag per 2000 reputation
- one bonus flag per 20 "flag weight" above the default
- maximum 100

Which then demands the question: what is flag weight?

Simply: it is the way we order flagged posts. Flags by known-good flaggers get seen first. This information is shown on your own profile if it is interesting (not too close the the default, i.e. you've done something worth showing), but basically:

- start at 100
- +10 for a flagged post (+5 for a comment) that we did something about (or was basically valid)
- -10 for a flagged post (-5 for a comment) that we suppressed as invalid
- min 0, max 750 (but non-linear above 500)
- **IMPORTANT CHANGE** - if you flag so consistently badly that you reach 0 weight, flags will be suppressed

If your flag weight is getting low you can quickly recover it simply by flagging sensibly. "I disagree with this" is a bad reason to flag, as is adding a moderator-message to say "plz answer post is urgent mail me".

Comment: Hm... so I have 37 flags. 10 default, plus 10-11 for the new 2k limit (depending on whether it updates my flags for my rep throughout the day, I imagine not though). That leaves around 16-17 points for the flag weight. Looks like we now have a method for people to determine their flag weight. ♪ (Huh... have I really cast so many mod flags here?)

Comment: `I totally agree with this. @Marc is my hero – Pekka 37 mins ago` Next time leave a comment @Pekka they're there for a reason

Comment: @Grace or easier... Wait for the next build

Comment: Will the flag weight be visible on all sites eventually?  Is there a minimum rep?  So far I can only see it on SO.

Comment: @JeffM at the moment we only show it if it outside a middle band

Comment: I really like this change, except why cap the flag weight so low? I have max flag weight yet I still only get ~50 flags, which I quickly run out of when I spend a few minutes going through /review. If my flags are >50% valid, surely mods are happy if I continue flagging past the current limit?

Comment: I have a flag weight of 230 and my rep is under 2K.  Shouldn't this mean I should have 23 flags?  Currently, I have 16.

Comment: @John - typo in the numbers; fixed

Comment: An enthusiastic +1, since this solves two of my problems: frequently running out of flags and worrying about whether my flags were considered welcome. It's too bad that displaying flag weight pretty much kills my Vexillolophile badge suggestion, though.

Comment: @Ivo I was joking. And testing the flag weight feature of course. (to no avail, seeing as one bad flag isn't enough for the weight to show up in the profile) :)

Comment: Too bad you're jokes cost me work @Pekka :P *Boy you make me look grumpy!*

Comment: @Ivo I'll make it up somehow one day. ;)

Comment: @Marc so flagging comments that ask someone to email are 'bad' flags? In other words, we'll lose points for it?

Comment: @George: I think he meant the other way around, as in if you flag your own question asking for a quick answer from the moderators via email.

Comment: "Good" and "bad" should most likely be understood just like the upvotes/downvotes. Correctly flagging something = good flag; Wrongly flagging something = bad flag. So flagging a "mail me" comment is *good* because the comment isn't helpful, but flagging a reasonable "I disagree because..:" is *bad* because the comment *adds value* and thus shouldn't be flagged.

Comment: @george - I was unclear; I meant a *moderator message* of the "plz help is urgent" kind. We just ***love*** getting those.

Comment: Is my maths failing me or should the MAX be = 10 (default) + 50 (rep) + 20 (weight) = 80?

Comment: As an FYI, I'm not sure the flag weight calculation for additional flags is working quite right today.  I started the day at 48 flags (10 base + 38 for reputation), yet I should have a few more for my 500 flag weight.  It seemed like I had more flags yesterday.  Did I overflow something?

Comment: @Brad - howso 38? I make it 10 + 15 + 20 = 45...?

Comment: @Marc - Ah, per 2000 reputation now.  Somehow I had misread the change from being per 1000 reputation.  Never mind, my bad.

Comment: Should you reach 0 do you dismiss flags silently or show a "no longer accepting flags from this account" message?

Comment: Since bad flags cause work for Mods and should only be used when the user is pretty certain it's correct to flag, I'd say adjust the weight by +2/-10 for good/bad flagging. Right now, you won't lose any flag weight even if _half_ of your flags are bad. Isn't that the kind of flagging behavior this was trying to suppress?

Comment: @Richard It was probably originally a max of 100 for when it was one flag per 1000 reputation.

Comment: @grace - there's a bit of tongue-in-cheek in there. The answer needs updating. Am I too vague? That's the 2nd time I had to explain myself today, although this is an old comment

Comment: @Marc: Can you please update your answer to the new 750 cap? (Maybe just add the new stuff at the top so the present answer is still there?)

Comment: @Marc, can the Community user be made exempt from the 0 flag weight suppression?  It's getting perilously close to 0 on SO.  I think some of its flagging algorithms need to be tweaked as well.  :)

Comment: @Bill actually, when Community flags something it uses an inbuilt constant weight. Still worth doing though.

Comment: This might need updating - looks like there's fractional flag weight now too.

Comment: This looks like it needs updating, since flag weight is now gone.

Comment: @MarcGravell, can you add the detailed info to http://stackoverflow.com/privileges/flag-posts bottom section?

Comment: Since you get one flag for every 20 points of your flag weight, shouldn't the max flag weight be 740 or 760 instead of 750?  ;-)