# Badge for reaching a high flag weighting score?

Tags: discussion, status-completed, badges, flags, flag-weight

*Due to the wider information released about the [flag weighting system](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/79742/are-the-new-moderator-flag-limits-sufficiently-high/80117#80117) and the fact that a user's flag weight is now revealed to them (well, sometimes):*

As one of the new moderators on SU I've notice that a pretty small subset of users do a lot of the really good flagging, so **I wonder if there should be a new badge created to be awarded to users that manage to the reach the maximum weighting score** (or a lower threshold, or maybe two badges for different score levels, etc - whatever makes the most sense in terms of current flag weights I guess).

This will give a small reward (as well as being responded to first, of course) to the users who really make an effort to help keep the sites clean, and will hopefully encourage the same positive behaviour in newer and current users who currently don't bother.

I also wonder if worthwhile modifing the Citizen Patrol badge to award it only after a user has a flag accepted as valid, not when they post a flag, although I can see this causing confusion (why didn't I get my badge posts, etc) without some very careful wording, so this isn't something I'm really pushing.

Comment: Some users might object to that, as it would be obvious to everyone that they frequently flag things. Additionally, while I don't want to _discourage_ flags, I don't want to encourage people to flag stuff just to win a badge, I'm afraid that might drop the signal to noise ratio. Still, I really would like to see the people who do a lot of the heavy lifting rewarded in some way. +1 for the idea of rewarding them, but I'm not sure about the badge.

Comment: @Tim Hmmm, a good point RE privacy. And if they're flagging wildly to get the badge they're likely to lose flag weight anyway; they won't get the badge, and their flags will drop to the bottom of the list. Although, I guess this is much less of a problem on every other site compared to SO so I probably miss some perspective in terms of volume...

Comment: Aside: What values would be "high". I mean, I know what my weighting score is but have no idea what the distribution looks like. I am a flagging god, a loser, or just this guy who sometimes flags things?

Comment: @dmckee - according to info elsewhere (like the [link](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/79742/are-the-new-moderator-flag-limits-sufficiently-high/80117#80117) in the question) the flag weight maxes out at a value of 500, so this is probably the "default" target in my mind - but the team would have to assess the current distribution for a suitable threshold if anything was to be introduced.

Comment: It appears that this is now completed with the "Deputy" badge: http://stackoverflow.com/badges/1002/deputy

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As per @Brad Larson's comment the new "Deputy" badge has appeared which seems to match this suggested criteria (ie, hit max flag weight).

<sup>Answering so I can ticking this off, and have also flagged for status-complete.</sup>