# Create a badge for excellence in site maintenance/flagging

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, flags, badge-request, review

When I saw [the "flag weight displayed in profile" announcement](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/80117/are-the-new-moderator-flag-limits-sufficiently-high) a few days ago, I left a comment stating that it eliminated the need for a badge I was about to propose. But with a few tweaks, I think the badge could still be useful.

It's well-established at this point that most badges exist to encourage good behaviors, and most of the remainder exist to alert users to features they might otherwise not know about. Flagging has a "notification badge" — [Citizen Patrol](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/badges/8/citizen-patrol) — but no "good behavior badge."

Flagging is an important part of keeping the site running efficiently, but it's often overlooked. We need to encourage people to think of it as a regular part of using the site, not a feature reserved for rare, exceptional conditions. This is especially true now that the devs have overhauled the flagging system to make it more accessible/less scary. So, we should have a badge for users who meet the following two criteria:

- Raised 1000 total flags
- Earned flag weight of 400 or greater

This could also be modified with a third parameter to encourage people to visit [the `/review` page](https://stackoverflow.com/review), which is currently not encouraged by anything at all. Perhaps one of the following conditions would do:

- Submitted at least 25% of total flags from `/review`
  **or**
- Submitted at least 200 total flags from `/review`
  **or**
- Flagged at least one post from `/review` every day for ten consecutive days

Pending tweaking of the exact numbers, **I propose creating the silver-level Vexillophile badge** for this. It's not really gold-worthy, but it's a marked step up from the bronze Citizen Patrol.

EDIT:
I don't want to see a suggested edits criterion added for this badge. The edit review system is important, but it's not related to flagging, so it should have its own badge. If I recall correctly, there is actually one in the works.

Comment: Did you misspell [Vexillophile](http://www.google.com.au/search?sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8&q=Vexillolophile) on purpose? :P

Comment: Just wondering, is there anywhere a direct link to `/review`?

Comment: Regarding site maintenance: Approving/rejecting edits could also play a role here (or could even get its own badge).

Comment: @BalusC A link to `/review` will replace the Unasnwered questions tab at the top of the page at some point in the future. In the meantime, you can try out [Benjol's userscript](http://stackapps.com/questions/2069/change-unanswered-tab-to-review) that does the same thing.

Comment: @Jon, if by "on purpose" you mean "typoed it earlier and then copy-pasted it to over here," then yes!

Comment: I'm... not really for *requiring* the /review route. Some people seem to police quite well without needing it, so it seems a bit arbitrary. Promoting it isn't a bad idea, but it's hardly necessary to be a good flagger.

Comment: Am I the only one who thinks 1000 total flags is extremely high ? If anyone ever reach that point he should become a moderator.

Comment: I think it should be "Have had a flag weight of 400 or greater for at least 4 weeks" AND Raised 1000 total flags AND Raised at least 100 flags in each of the last 4 weeks.  (E.g. be good and keep being good)

Comment: This needs a silver and a gold badge, Citizen Patrol is the bronce badge.

Comment: @status-completed The only thing (small though, so it's not a show-stopper) that concerns me is that raising 1000 flags would mean that there's been at least 1000 danger items that needed to be flagged. Easy number for Stack Overflow (even if it'll take around 2-3 months due to flag limits), but a very bad number for the smaller sites.

Comment: Possibly not activated yet, but [check this out](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/badges/140/deputy "Probably not implemented yet because he wasn't shot")

Comment: ...I'm taking credit for that. (@Grace)

Comment: @Grace It's active now, myself and 13 others just got it [on SO](http://stackoverflow.com/badges/1002/deputy). It surprises me the number is so low. :-/

Comment: I'm a deputy!!!  That's a fun badge name.

Comment: @HoLyVieR Needing to raise 1,000 helpful flags is extremely high? I dunno. I have that many on SO, and I would make a terrible janitor.  That said, the other person I know in that range did get elected moderatrix not too long bag. But I bet we see a drop-off at 500, because people might feel there is no longer an incentive to flag.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Completed in spirit with Marshal and Deputy:

https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/08/a-bevy-of-new-badges/

Answer (score 4):

This has already been done

https://stackoverflow.com/badges/1002/deputy

Although the criteria is a bit different from your proposal.  From the surface, it looks like it is just "Hit 500 flag weight"

Comment: I can't believe how few people have this. As _soon_ as I found out about the flag weight thing, I was determined to get capped. Then I found there was a badge for it.