# Link from Badges list to dataexplorer query to show how close/far you are

Tags: feature-request, badges, data-explorer

When viewing a list of [badge recipients](https://stackoverflow.com/badges/805/sportsmanship) it would be handy to have a link that goes to a query in the dataexplorer to show how close/far you are from achieving that badge. User and badge ID could be passed as url params.

(Inspired by waffles' comment on [Strunk-and-White problem?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/80166/strunk-and-white-problem/80405#80405))

Answer (score 1):

This is not always possible.

For example, see this question: [SEDE translation of Legendary badge query](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/80286/156011)
or the data for the latest badge <sup>(as at 25-Feb-2011)</sup>: [Create a badge for excellence in site maintenance/flagging](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/80437/156011)

SE DataExplorer does not have enough data to model a good portion of the queries.

The second and more crucial issue is that you want such a link to be able to check frequently - well, SEDE is  updated weekly (on Monday)

https://data.stackexchange.com/faq

> **How frequently is Stack Exchange Data Explorer updated?**
> The data is updated early every Monday morning around 3:00 UTC. The last update was Apr 26 at 6:43.