# Why did my number of remaining "inform moderator flags" go up?

Tags: discussion, flags

Yesterday I had 10 maximum flags. I flagged two posts for attention: one to be migrated to meta, and one that wasn't really a question. Today I have 12 maximum flags. Was I credited with a higher maximum for my actions, or was this something else?

Comment: Might flag this to test if I lose moderator flag points for miss-flagging ;)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's because your flag weight increased by 40, probably as result of good flagging.

See this post for the full details: [Are the new moderator flag limits sufficiently high?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/79742/are-the-new-moderator-flag-limits-sufficiently-high/80117#80117)

The relevant line is:

> one bonus flag per 20 "flag weight"
>   above the default (capped at 500 flag
>   weight)