# Can a Brother Get Some More Flags, Please?

Tags: discussion, flags, vote-to-close

I use up all my flags every day and my close votes.

For a super flagger and closer like myself, it would be nice if the system could somehow recognize this and give me more flags to use.

As a 10K+ user, there are plenty of opportunities for me to help clean up the morass. I'd like to help more, but why should I be penalized by only having 46 flags and 50 close votes.

I feel I could be much more beneficial to site if I had more flags and close votes by which to work with.

I understand that there is a formula for this and I'm not trying to game the system (though I am up to 742 flag weight as of this posting due to my extensive flagging). I just want to help out more and when I run out, well I can't really do much more.

Comment: You do get some extra flags based on rep, but it's pretty slow. At 20.8k rep I have 52 flags per day (at 750 flag weight).

Comment: @hammar: Yea that's my point. You should have at least a 100 IMHO at that rep.

Comment: Just for reference, the maximum number of flags anyone can have per day is currently 80, as explained [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/79742/are-the-new-moderator-flag-limits-sufficiently-high/80117#80117).

Comment: *Only* 46?  We used to have only 5-10 of each.  GET OFF MY LAWN, WHIPPERSNAPPER!

Comment: Ah, I remember those days. I must have earned 90% of my flag weight on every site in the week after `/review` was introduced and the flag quota was raised.

Comment: I think this request should be for Stack Overflow only. I rarely use all my close votes, but I do sometimes use all my flags if I go on a spree, and never am I participating in anywhere near too large a proportion of the day's flags. On other sites, it's possible you could have too much influence as a percent of material reflagged / voted on if the number of flags was increased too much.

Comment: @PopularDemand - fwiw, I think the maximum n. flags p.d. is 92 since the max flag weight was raised to 750.

Comment: @martinclayton I doubt it, because Marc explicitly says "one bonus flag per 20 'flag weight' above the default __(capped at 500 flag weight)__ " (emphasis mine) in the same post that acknowledges the increase of max flag weight to 750.

Comment: @Popular Demand the "at 500" is simply text that pre-dates the > 500 changes. No artificial cap on flag-weight is applied here.

Comment: Firstly there is more value to the site in you flaging a post that someone else has not already flagged, so you can use the 10K tools to see where your flags can add the most value.

Comment: @IanRingrose: Yes but with a higher flag weight, my flag is given greater priority so the morass is cleaned up faster. 

I'm already doing everything else (downvoting, upvoting, editing, suggested approvals/rejections on edits, etc). I WANT MOAR! ;)

Answer (score 23):

When you spend all your flags and close votes, maybe you can spend some time actually answering questions, or perhaps - going offline. So, in such point of view, the limit is to protect yourself from getting addicted and dying from an overdose :)

Comment: I do it all - going offline though? Are you crazy?! ;)

Comment: What is this "off the line" you speak of?

Comment: @PaddedCell I meant the world you would see, if you turn off your computer, as well as your smartphone and any other devices with network access ;)

Comment: @Darhazer: Computers can be turned off?

Answer (score 9):

> why should I be penalized by only having 46 flags and 50 close votes

I'm not sure the word "only" belongs anywhere near the rest of that sentence.

Seems to me that this would only affect Stack Overflow, as no other site has enough volume to need so much flagging/close-voting. Even on SO, it'd affect only a tiny number of users, since there are fewer than 900 Deputies. On top of that, most Deputies aren't 10k-ers; some count their rep in the *hundreds*.

I assume you're flagging and closing appropriately because of your stellar flag weight, but you are an edge case unto yourself. (I would like to see a list of all the posts you flag and vote to close in a day though, just for fun. Or perhaps, to be more useful, your strategies for finding posts in need of flags/close votes.)

Comment: My strategy is simple. I look for "not an answer" posts that float in the Tools menu. I ignore the very low quality flags first. Many flags are close reasons so I will go read the post really quick and then close it for the reason I feel. If there is nothing left to flag (and I have flags left), then I go away for a while to let the flags show up in the 10K tools area. Or, I may go to the Review tab and see the "low quality" posts. After perusing that, I may find more "not an answer" posts or "very low quality" posts that require flagging. Eventually I run out and it does not take 24 hrs.

Comment: «I'm not sure the word "only" belongs anywhere near the rest of that sentence.» Or the word "penalized". This _isn't_ a penalty -- nothing's being taken away, and 0A0D is probably in the top 1% by flag inventory.

Comment: Agreed, @ἸησοῦςCaswell. The original version of this post only copied "only having 46 flags and 50 close votes" and I didn't change my wording after I pasted in more.

Comment: @ἸησοῦςCaswell: It sure feels like a penalty.

Comment: @0A0D: You and I are in the same boat. I have taken up the impossible task of clearing the **Late Answers queue of 61,476 posts** armed with only 35 Upvotes and 46 delete flags daily. And in the /tools my favourites are "Not an answer" they're usually right.

Answer (score 6):

> I understand that there is a formula for this and I'm not trying to game the system (though I am up to 742 flag weight as of this posting due to my extensive flagging). I just want to help out more and when I run out, well I can't really do much more.

We appreciate it, but these increases are already in effect, per:

[Are the new moderator flag limits sufficiently high?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/79742/are-the-new-moderator-flag-limits-sufficiently-high/80117#80117)

> - default 10 moderator flags per day (5 when talking about spam/offensive)
> - one bonus flag per 2000 reputation
> - one bonus flag per 20 "flag weight" above the default
> - maximum 100 flags