# What do I do when I run out of flags?

Tags: support, flags

**The problem:**  There is a [post that needs to be flagged here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3683498/894284) (now 10k+ only) and I'm out of flags.

**The meta-problem:**  What should I do when I run out of flags (early) in the day, but see lots of crap?
<sub>wait?  i don't wanna!!</sub>

Comment: Yes, wait. Add comments and with any luck others will see and flag.

Comment: On average, just how many flags do you use per day? If you're consistently flagging things helpfully, you should have upwards of 50 flags, which should be enough for anyone. :-)

Comment: I went through 43 or more today.

Comment: No idea how people run into that many flag worthy posts. Especially without mod tools.

Comment: @CodeInChaos, work the [Review](http://stackoverflow.com/review/) link. You'll find lots.

Comment: Set your hair on fire and run circles around the post in question?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Cancel misclicked flags](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/87500/cancel-misclicked-flags)

Comment: If you are flagging well, over time you will be given more and more flags to use each day.  Be patient.  Flag well.

Comment: Wait, you only ran out of flags this _one time_? [Lightweight.](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/107769/can-a-brother-get-some-more-flags-please)

Comment: Vote for [bonus flags](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/115553/bonus-moderation-flags-for-users-who-have-an-extremely-helpful-flag-record-for-t)!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Probably the best thing to do for the short term is add it to your Favorites and flag it the next day.  In this particular case the post is from 2010, so it's not terribly urgent (I deleted it anyway, naturally).  In the long term, keep raising useful flags and the number that you can cast in a day will go up.

Answer (score 3):

One option is to tell somebody in chat so that they can flag it for you. Otherwise, just wait. If it's in a visible place, somebody else will see it soon enough. If not, it's not doing too much damage, so it can wait.