# Flagging History Summary

Tags: support, declined-flags, flag-weight, flag-history

Are the flags above the blue line totals and the one's below  partial summaries?

---

[image: flagging history]

Also, what is considered a good flagging history?
*I  want  an idea whether I have too many declined of disputed flags.*

---

[image: daily flags]

---

**note**
***Whomever guess correctly what the little animal heads are in the image gets marked as correct answer***

---

Does anyone think I'll be invited to be a [Stack Overflow Valued Associate](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/06/welcome-stack-overflow-valued-associates-00006-and-00007/), based on my unicorn pictures?
*See Assoc #00007's profile :))*

Comment: Nearly 95% of your flags were deemed helpful. I don't know what par is, but that seems pretty good to me.

Comment: am I allowed to know what my flag weight is.. and what a good or bad  flag weight is? I came after the time flag weights were removed from profiles

Comment: Related: [Interpreting My Flagging History Sidebar](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/157344)

Comment: @CodyGray I used to think that all these totals were added together. Which reduced my flag success (don't ask me why I thought they were added together..

Comment: @CodyGray I did search.. I can show you the links.. omg..

Comment: hang on, now I'm confused.., are the flags below the blue line summaries, or do all the corresponding flags need to be totalled??  http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/157345/223277

Comment: No, they'd need to be totalled. Each little block refers to different types of flags.

Comment: Then how did you get 95%?? I get 90%

Comment: I'm bad at math. That's why I threw in that "nearly" qualifier, since I was just guessing. Which I shouldn't do, because my guesses are bad. Anyway, I'd say 90% is very near 95%. :-)

Comment: so what is a good flagging success? and what would my flag rate be?

Comment: @Skippy What do the letters mean next to the unicorns?

Comment: @DannyBeckett great question.. when I was designing my pic (I was waiting for a software download - hence the attention to detail).. I decided to group them in colour, than realised letters may be better, then realised I'd given the top group the same letters as the bottom group, so used a blue line instead to draw the distinction.. In principle, I was going to say does A + B= C, but totally stuffed it up hahahhaahahaha

Comment: doe anyone know how we know, how many flags we get a day??

Comment: It changes, depending on a number of different factors.

Comment: @Skippy Just click `flag` and have a look at the number (I think after midnight UTC).

Comment: @DannyBeckett yes, I thought of that, am reading up about flag weight.. for me some of the confusion wa the change in the flag badges, they used to have a minimum success rate

Comment: @CodyGray does this http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/80117/223277 still stand?

Comment: No idea. Potentially, since they still use flag weight internally, it is just not exposed publically. But I'll ask you what I ask all the time on the main site: what problem are you trying to solve? Why do you need to know this? Are you running out of flags? Did a moderator send you a message telling you to stop flagging because your flags are generally wrong? If not, there's no problem. It doesn't matter.

Comment: @CodyGray I can't help it, I like to measure everything.. my performance at flagging, posting questions, answers, exams, assignments.. let's face it, many of the users here are slightly . em how can I put it delicately, number happy.. :). I thought I had a bad flagging history, and now I am realising it is good.. makes me happy

Comment: @Skippy Which question is being duplicated?

Comment: @Skippy: Seems unlikely.  All the other accounts on that IP are in good standing.

Comment: hm, ok.. my bad.. I just remember seeing a very similar question about android.. hm.. I'll show you another link from another site and u can tell me what u think

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The very top number is the total number of "normal" flags you've raised:

[image]

Below that is the breakdown of *that* total:

[image]

= 555

---

The next 3 lines are in relation to your spam flags:

[image]

Here you have 13 posts total that you've flagged as spam. The breakdown is 9 + 4 = 13.

---

The same goes for the last 2 blocks - they're in relation to your *offensive* and comment flags:

[image]

---

As for a good flag rate, I believe that *I* have a good flag rate, and here's mine:

[image]

So you should just aim to have a low *declined* rate (which you do have).

<sup>Aside: Boycott! [Remove the max flags per day restriction for good flaggers](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/177742/remove-the-max-flags-per-day-restriction-for-good-flaggers)</sup>

---

Ok I'll have a guess at what the animals are, since you wanted to know `:P` Is it: Blue unicorn, yellow unicorn, green unicorn, red unicorn, pink unicorn, blue unicorn, green unicorn, red unicorn, blue unicorn, green unicorn, blue unicorn, green unicorn, *super* unicorn? `:D`

Comment: @Skippy From my understanding, flag weight is meaningless nowadays.